# Want to acces object in requests array of profile in users collection

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

> i want to create a event in which by clicking on accept in the
>   termplate i want to get that respective object of requests array in
>   profile of users collection

this profile section of my users collection `(accounts-password)`

```
{
    "profile": {
        "name": {
            "first_name": "Vibhor",
            "last_name": "Yadav"
        },
        "college_name": "ssit",
        "gender": "MALE",
        "friends": [],
        "requests": [{
            "id": "z6rDkvayDA5Ckoeab",
            "name": "Nitin Gupta"
        }],
        "requested": [{
            "id": "M6edD427rG9WwhfNh",
            "name": "suraj Kumar"
        }]
    }
```

template to print requests

```
<template name = "notification">
    <div id="req-main-div">
        <ul>
            {{# each username in reqList}}
                <li>
                    <div id="req-user-name" value={{username.name}}>{{username.name}}</div>
                    <div id="accept">accept</div>
                    <div id="delete">delete</div>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

helper to the template

```
Template.notification.helpers({
    reqList:function () {
        var User = Meteor.user();
        return User.profile.requests;
    }
});
```

the method i tried

```
 Template.notification.events({
        'click #accept':function(){
            console.log(document.getElementById('req-user-name').value);
            Meteor.call('accept_request',this);
        }
    });
```

i am not able to access DOM too

```
accept_request:function(accept){
    if(!Meteor.userId())
    {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized','you are not signed in');
    }
    var user = Meteor.user();
    console.log(accept);
}
```

iam getting this on console

```
undefined//for DOM of # accept
Object// for accept in accept_request method
main: ()
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: For starters, you should not use the same `id` for multiple DOM nodes, use `class` instead (and what's the meaning of the `value` attribute for the `div`?). Get the data that you need in the event handler (from DOM or otherwise) and send it as an argument to the server. On the server, validate the data and update the database. Where are you getting stuck? I assume `this` in your handler contains the user details, as its data context is the `requestList` item.

Comment: @Morteza sir _this_  contain array  named 'requests' ...i want to acces object of the aray [{id:  and  name:}]  in my 'accept_request' method so that i can add that user in 'friends'  array inside 'profile'.....thanks for ur 'class' suggestion :-).

Comment: @Vibhor Do you see any elements with id =`eq-user-name` in **Browser Inspect Element**?

Comment: its  "id =req-user-name"   sir